# How do I deserialize data from a file and cast it back to the original object?

Tags: c#, serialization

For some reason when I try to write the code to deserialize the data back to an object I keep getting the error "Cannot convert type method to Form1.Account". I have tried to do an explicit cast but that is not working either. Can someone please advise what I am doing wrong. As you see from the screenshot below my object is accounts

[image]

This is the data that was Serialized that I am wanting to Deserialize and cast back to the object accounts (Am I understanding this correctly?)

[image]

This is the code where the account(object) is originally created and also where I serialize the data.

```
        private int _nextIndex = 0;
    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();

    const string FILENAME = "Data.ser";
    FileStream outFile = new FileStream(FILENAME,
        FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
    BinaryFormatter bFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();

            if (checkingRadioButton1.Checked == true)
            {
                _nextIndex++;
                transactionLabel3.Text = "Checking Account: #" + _nextIndex + " created with a starting balance of $" + balance;
                accountTextBox1.Text = "" + _nextIndex;
                accounts.Add(new CheckingAccount(balance)
                {
                    AccountID = _nextIndex
                    ,
                    Student = isStudent
                });
                bFormatter.Serialize(outFile, accounts);
            }
            else if (savingsRadioButton2.Checked == true)
            {
                _nextIndex++;
                transactionLabel3.Text = "Savings Account: #" + _nextIndex + "  created with a starting balance of $" + balance;
                accountTextBox1.Text = "" + _nextIndex;
                accounts.Add(new SavingsAccount(balance)

                {
                    AccountID = _nextIndex
                   ,
                    Senior = isSenior
                });
                bFormatter.Serialize(outFile, accounts);
            }
```

The code below I also Serialize data and at the end I am attempting to Deserialize the data butI keep getting the error I mentioned above.

```
            if (depositRadioButton3.Checked == true)
            {
                selectedAccount.DepositFunds(amount);
                bFormatter.Serialize(outFile, accounts);
                transactionLabel3.Text = $"Account: #{selectedAccount.AccountID} You made a deposit of ${amount}";
            }
            else if (withdrawRadioButton4.Checked == true)
            {
                var balance = selectedAccount.GetAvailableBalanceForAccount(accountID);
                if (selectedAccount.HasAvailableFunds && amount <= balance)
                {
                    selectedAccount.WithdrawFromAccount(amount);
                    bFormatter.Serialize(outFile, accounts);
                    transactionLabel3.Text = $"Account: #{selectedAccount.AccountID} You made a withdrawal of ${amount}";
                    outFile.Close();
                    FileStream inFile = new FileStream(FILENAME, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    while (inFile.Position < inFile.Length)
                    {
                        accounts = (Account)bFormatter.Deserialize,(inFile);
                        accounts.

                    }
                }
```

Comment: Typo. Should be `bFormatter.Deserialize(inFile)` without the comma.

Comment: Yes that has been removed but still the same error. Must have been inserted while I was trying different things to fix the issue.

Comment: The class that you are using to de-serialize has to be exactly the same on that was used to serialize.  If you modified you code you have to go back and serialize the data before you deserialize.

Comment: @jdweng No my code hasn't changed. The only thing I have changed is the code I have tried to deserialize the data. The class I am using hasn't changed.

Comment: If you have removed the comma then please tell us what kind of error you're getting now then.

Comment: It should really be to just cast it back to the original object, if that isn't working for you, please tell us what happens instead. However, what about the serialization screenshot showing "Count = <something>", are you really serializing a list? If you are then you need to cast the deserialized object into a list as well.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen it is the same exact error as before  "Cannot convert type method to Form1.Account".

Comment: No, that's what the editor tells you **when you still have the comma present**. That's not the compiler error you would get, and if you really had removed the comma, it would probably compile but give you a runtime error instead.

Comment: Try flushing and close the output file when it is generated : outFile.Flush(); outFile.Close(). I suspect the file doesn't contain all the data so when you read the file you get an error.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I cannot compile it because there is nothing to compile meaning I first need to get the code written for Deserialization which is my original question. I am stuck on writing the Deserialization code.

Answer (score 4):

You appear to have *serialized* a list or array - quite possibly a `List<Account>`. I say this because it says "Count: 1".

There are two ways to proceed here:

1. try it: `var list = (List<Account>)bFormatter.Deserialize(inFile);` (and store that somewhere, presumably back into the `accounts` field)
2. or, inspect the object: `object obj = bFormatter.Deserialize(inFile); Console.WriteLine(obj.GetType().FullName);`

Note: based on `List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();` in your code, "1" will probably work fine.

I should also add that I usually advise *against* using `BinaryFormatter`. It is ... pretty brittle and unfriendly as you version your types, and I've seen a *lot* of people have problems with it. It also tends to be easy to accidentally suck in unexpected objects into your serialization graph, especially via events. There are other serialization tools that I would recommend - a range of xml, json, protobuf, etc serializers that are trusted and known to be hassle free. Personally I'm biased towards protobuf-net, but... again: bias.

Comment: While you're biased towards protobuf-net, I think every developer who has done some serialization is biased *away from* BinaryFormatter. It works, it works, it works, and then suddenly it doesn't work and you often have no real recourse but to rewrite the whole thing when you discover why.